# Creating multi-select tags via Notion API

Tags: javascript, node.js, notion-api, notion

I'm writing a programme to create a page under a Notion database using the API, but am having trouble getting the multi-select property to work

This is what I have written in properties { } (lines 67-76 of the code in my [index.js](https://github.com/learkonas/dosie/blob/master/index.js) in my repo)

```
  "multi-select": [
    { "name": tag1},
    { "name": tag2}
  ],
```

This is in an async function where tag1 and tag2 are string variables
But when I run the code I get the following error:

```
'code: validation_error',  message: 'body failed validation. Fix one:\n' + .... {"object":"error", ...
```

(It's too long to paste but that's the gist. I screenshotted the full error [here](https://prnt.sc/ehwby0K-kUZV).)

The code works perfectly when I comment these lines out.
I see no reason why this shouldn't work, so I suspect I have done something wrong in my set-up elsewhere, since I'm quite new to coding. The full repo is [here](https://github.com/learkonas/dosie/) - it's not long

Grateful for what I'm sure is probably a quick fix - thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things going on with how you're trying to define the the multi select property:

1. It should be `multi_select` not `multi-select`
2. The body should be an object with an array of options, not just an array. I think you've copied some stuff from an API response which looks a little different.

```
 "Tags": {
    "multi_select": {
           "options": [
            {
              "name": tag1, 
              "color": "red"
            },
            {
              "name": tag2,
              "color": "gray"
            }
          ]},
```

Comment: Thank you!! The multi_select was just a typo
There was also some trouble with the colours, since I was trying to put the same tag in a different colour

I don't think I am using your solution, but it did inspire me to find something that works, so thank you

What actually worked for me was the following:

        "Tags": { 
          "multi_select": [
            {
              "name": tag1,
              color: "red"
            },
            {
              "name": tag2,
              color: "blue"
            }
          ]
        },

Answer (score 0):

The format for the JSON above seems incorrect, here's an updated one if you're copy/pasting:

```
{
  "Tags": {
    "multi_select": {
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "tag1",
          "color": "red"
        },
        {
          "name": "tag2",
          "color": "gray"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```